# Check value of field of argument in Drools query

Tags: drools, rules, mvel

How would I check the value of an argument's field in a Drools query?

I have a Contract Java class I'm passing to the query:

```
public class Contract {
   ... other vars

   private prodContractNum;
   public String getProdContractNum() {
      return prodContractNum;
   }

   ... other getters
}
```

and I'd like to check the equality of the `prodContractNum` field. I've tried:

```
query checkContractNum(Contract contract)
   contract := Contract(prodContractNum == "D");
end
```

but that's not matching any of my Contract inputs. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why a query? Why can't you just do that in your rule? This really sounds like an XY problem where you're asking for help with your "solution" instead of the actual problem. You can trivially match on the attribute in your rule's left hand side: `Contract( prodContractNum == "D" )`.

Comment: More like a "fit this circle into square" problem. I'm trying to migrate a few hundred rules & conditions from another rules engine directly into drools - a direct translation seems like the easiest solution. In this case, I'd like to have a `checkContractNum` query that can be reused across multiple rules.

Comment: So why not just add the condition to the when clause? `Contract( prodContractNum == "D" )`

Comment: Apologies for not being more specific - a requirement for my program is external configuration of the rules and their conditions by business analysts. This information is stored in a DB that is loaded into my program at bootup and builds up the knowledge base using Drools templates. In my program, I'm treating queries as conditions for the rules. So, for example, `rule A` has conditions `B and C` but can be later changed externally to conditions `D and E` via DB changes and program reboot. Hence why I'm trying to use queries - they're easier to configure as blocks of logic for templating.